# Regex validation for pattern 20+99

Tags: java, regex, validation

Hi my requirement is like this

Required text format
20+99

1. maximum allowed number should be 20 for left side from the + mark
2. right side maximum number should be 99
3. should allow only two characters each side

Other allowed formats

1. 1+1
2. 0+0
3. 01+01

We tried followings

[0-9]{1,2}([+])[0-9]{1,2}

(^[01][0-9]|20)([+])[0-9]{1,2}

Problem with first approach is cannot limit left side to 20 and it allows more than 2 characters each side.

Problem with the second approach is it does not allow 1+1 or 0+0. 
Appreciate some support to modify the regex to cater our requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted from your second attempt :

```
^(?:[01]?[0-9]|20)\+[0-9]{1,2}$
```

Comment: same as above : (^[01][0-9]|^20)([+])[0-9]{1,2}$

Comment: This works. Some improvements : No need for `^` or `$` in java (OP is probably using `matches()`). Next, Use non capturing groups `(?:)` instead of  capturing ones `()`

Comment: @Aaron when use this in a java code I cannot have \. Whats wrong using ([+])?

Comment: @virtualpathum You must double the backslash in Java (`\\+`). `([+])` is overly verbose as in declares a character class of one character and enclose it in a group, but it would work too.